# Implement DFA/NFA/epsilon-NFA

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest code that implements a:

1. [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)
2. [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton)
3. [epsilon-NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton_with_%CE%B5-moves)

The program should accept as input:

- a string(that we want to see if is accepted or not)
- the delta function, represented in whichever way it's more convenient.
- the "set" of final states of the automaton

And it should output `Accepted!` if the string is accepted by the automaton, and the string `Not a chance!` otherwise.

Note that all inputs should be taken from stdin or the command line.

The total points should be computed as `(L1 + 2*L2 + 3*L3) / 6` where `Li` is the length, in bytes, of the code solving point `i` and the winner will be the answer with *smallest* score.

---

**Edit:** You can assume the starting state, so that it is *not* required as input.

The epsilon transitions can be labelled in any way you want.

---

**Edit2:** An example of input for the DFA:

```
0100
{'q_0': {'0': 'q_1', '1': 'q_0'}, 'q_1': {'0': 'q_2', '1': 'q_3'}, 'q_2': {'0': 'q_2', '1': 'q_3'}, 'q_3': {'1': 'q_0', '0': 'q_1'}}
{'q_2', 'q_3'}
```

Output:

```
Accepted!
```

An other input:

```
010010
{'q_0': {'0': 'q_1', '1': 'q_0'}, 'q_1': {'0': 'q_2', '1': 'q_3'}, 'q_2': {'0': 'q_2', '1': 'q_3'}, 'q_3': {'1': 'q_0', '0': 'q_1'}}
{'q_2', 'q_3'}
```

Output:

```
Not a chance!
```

I want to stress that you are free to use a different formatting for the inputs. Choose the simpler to "parse" in your target language. The above is simple to use in python since you can `eval` it to obtain the real objects.

Comment: How do we choose between 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: ...or do we write 3 separate programs?

Comment: @KeithRandall the scoring indicates three programs are desired.

Comment: Exactly, you have to produce three different programs, one for the DFA, one for the NFA and one for the epsilon-NFA. I chose to do so since they are stricly related(hence it doesn't make sense to ask 3 different questions).

Comment: Can we get some example inputs / outputs?

Comment: @boothby I'll now add an example, but keep in mind that you are free to change the formatting of the input if a different formatting is more convenient. The example I'll write is probably a convenient way for the python solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, score = 138 1/6 = (79+108*2+178*3)/6

### DFA

```
S,D,F=input()
s=1
for c in S:s=D[s,c]
print["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0]
```

Input is a triple of string `S`, a delta function `D`, and final state mask `F`.  I number each state with a power of 2, so `F` is just the OR of each accepting state.  `D` is a map from (state,input char)->state.

example input (accepts all strings ending in `b`):

```
'abab',{(1,'a'):1,(1,'b'):2,(2,'a'):1,(2,'b'):2},2
```

### NFA

```
S,D,F=input()
s=1
for c in S:
 t,s=s,0
 for a,b in D[c]:s|=t/a%2*b
print["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0]
```

We number states as powers of 2 as before.  `D` is a map from input character to a list of transitions labeled by that character.

example input (accepts all strings ending in `b`):

```
'abab',{'a':[(1,1)],'b':[(1,1),(1,2)]},2
```

### epsilon-NFA

```
S,D,F=input()
E={1:1}
for i in D[0]:
 for a,b in D[0]:E[a]=a|E.get(b,b)
s=E[1]
for c in S:
 t,s=s,0
 for a,b in D[c]:s|=t/a%2*E.get(b,b)
print["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0]
```

Same as `NFA`, but with the additional `0` character listing the epsilon transitions.

example input (accepts all strings ending in `b`):

```
'abab',{'a':[(1,1)],'b':[(1,1),(1,2)],0:[(2,4)]},2
```

Comment: i think you win